# Additive identities of Hom-sets in Ab-categories

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Weibel (in Introduction to Homological Algebra) defines **Ab** categories as those categories whose Hom-sets have an Abelian group structure compatible with composition. He doesn't require them to have zero objects, which he later adds to the definition of additive categories. I understand that once a category contains a zero object then there is a zero morphism between any two objects in that category.

In the Appendix on Abelian categories we are asked to show that in **Ab** categories $f:B\to C$ is monic $\iff$ for every non-zero $e:A\to B$, $fe\neq 0$.

I believe that here $0$ stands for the additive identity in $\text{Hom}(A,C)$ i.e. $g+0=g$ for all $g\in \text{Hom}(A,C)$. Is this the zero morphism $0_{AC}$ as well? I believe I need to check that $0\circ h_1=0\circ h_2$ and $h_3\circ 0=h_4\circ 0$ for all compatible morphisms $h_1,\dots,h_4$.

To prove the exercise statement I think all I need is $fe=0=f\circ 0 \implies e=0$ when $f$ is monic and for the converse $fg=fh$ $\implies$ $f(g-h)=0$ (as we are in **Ab** categories) which implies $g=h$ (as $fe=0$ only when $e=0$). But I am a bit confused about what $0$ means here. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Yes, $0$ means the zero morphism. Your proof is correct.

Comment: Thank you Qiaochu. So, whenever we have $\textbf{Ab}$-categories we also have all the required zero morphisms?

Comment: Yes, all of the Homsets are abelian groups so they all have zero elements and these are zero morphisms (by bilinearity). I go over stuff like this in excruciating detail here (because I also wanted to get all the details of this stuff straight): https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/a-meditation-on-semiadditive-categories/

Comment: Thank you so much :)) I sometimes get bothered by details, so this is very useful!!

Comment: You're welcome. Abelian category stuff can be confusing because there are several surprisingly strong uniqueness properties in play, e.g. zero morphisms are unique (in a similar way as identity morphisms), biproducts are unique (in a very strong sense, stronger than the usual limit / colimit stuff; you have no choices whatsoever when you adjoin biproducts to an $\text{Ab}$-enriched category), the abelian group structures in an additive category are unique...